# Just simple key but not work(Python3.5x)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know why. I already downloaded Python and just use at first. plz help me.
[image]

Comment: You should post code as properly formatted text, not as image

Comment: your `else` case is empty and in some cases not properly indented (it should be aligned with the `if`)

Answer (score 2):

Should look like this:

```
>>> if hungry:
        print("...")
else:
        print("...")
```

This only applies to interactive shell because the `>>>` aren't counted for indentation by the shell.